# Comparing 2 variables

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to compare 2 scores that I have made lastScore and best_score(both in Main_Screen). If lastScore is higher than bestScore I want it to change the best_score to the lastScore.There are no errors but if the lastScore is lower than best_score, I don't want it to change. The only problem is that the score changes regardless of whether the lastScore is higher or lower. Thanks in advance.

https://github.com/alex578344/FirstApp

Comment: Something weird for me is that you do not use the `retrieve` and `save`functions you wrote so it can be that the best score is never saved and that's maybe why you have problems. Could it be ?

Comment: Yeah I've tried using them but I only encounter problems. That's why I was hoping for some clarification on when and where to save and retrieve the variables

Comment: Ok, I see. I'll post a quick response.

Comment: Look in my edit in main post. It still changes no matter what and I would really like some info on where to put the save and retrieve because I am really not sure @LaurentMeyer

Comment: Your edits are correct to me. Do you receive some values from `getIntent().getExtras()` or from `retrieveInt()` ? Because your code looks ok.

Comment: I'm not sure. I am using both but I think its probs the best_Score that is not saving a score. Do I have to sure Log. to find out? @Laurent Meyer

Comment: Could you post your code (the project) on Github (or Bitbucket), because it's complicated to solve such a bug without having the whole thing. (of course, if it's a proprietary code, do not do it but it'll be then a bit more complicated to debug)

Comment: @LaurentMeyer There I uploaded it. Link above. Thanks for any help you can give

Comment: Done :), Look at your pull requests ;)

Comment: I am so grateful for your help. I would of been stuck for a long time. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome but you didn't merge the request. Guess it'd be easier instead of copy paste (and I would have a reminder on your repository in order to help you if you need to in the next steps)

Comment: Yeah sorry I've never used GitHub before, only got it for this, but I guess it is quite usefull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Apurva said, you have to use the shared Preferences like this:

```
public void saveInfo(int bestScore) {
     SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
     editor.putInt("BEST_SCORE", bestScore);
}

public int retrieveInt() {
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    return sp.getInt("BEST_SCORE", 0);
}
```